# How to get an element's rect BEFORE a transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rect, getboundingclientrect

Currently, `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` gives the position and dimensions of an element, but it automatically accounts for transformations via the CSS `transform` property. How can I get the rectangle **without** the transformation?

In the example below, I would want the output to be `10 10 100 100`.

```js
const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect()
document.write(`${rect.left} ${rect.top} ${rect.width} ${rect.height}`)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

div {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) scale(0.5)
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Why not remove the transform property, measure it, then add the property back again?

Comment: I considered doing that, but my gut tells me there should be a simpler way. I'd be pretty surprised if there wasn't a built-in for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745438/how-to-compute-getboundingclientrect-without-considering-transforms

Answer (score 4):

> Here is already an answer, you can read more on this post:
>   [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

So, you can get the actual value "before" transform by changing your code to the following

```js
document.write(`${div.offsetLeft} ${div.offsetTop} ${div.offsetWidth} ${div.offsetHeight}`)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

div {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) scale(0.5)
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```