# How to compute getBoundingClientRect() in a scaled svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a usecase where designers supply us with a SVG, and we use certain elements in that SVG to position our dynamically created elements.

In the snippet below I try to overlap the rect#overlayTarget with the div#overlay using `getBoundingClientRect`: it doesn't take the scaling of the parent element into account, and the elements don't overlap.

The answers from this question is not applicable here as it uses `element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop`, which aren't available for SVG: [How to compute getBoundingClientRect() without considering transforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745438/how-to-compute-getboundingclientrect-without-considering-transforms)

How do I make the #overlay and #overlayTarget overlap?

```js
const target = document.querySelector("#overlayTarget");
const position = target.getBoundingClientRect();

const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");
overlay.style.top = `${position.y}px`;
overlay.style.left = `${position.x}px`;
overlay.style.width = `${position.width}px`;
overlay.style.height = `${position.height}px`;
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: hotpink;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" style="transform: scale(0.875);">
  Test
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1809" height="826" viewBox="0 0 809 826">
        <g
          id="Main_overview"
          data-name="Main overview"
          transform="translate(-49.5 -155)"
        >
          <g
            id="overlayTarget"
            data-name="DC-DC converter"
            transform="translate(400 512)"
          >
            <rect
              id="Rectangle_29"
              data-name="Rectangle 29"
              width="74"
              height="74"
              fill="none"
              stroke="#47516c"
              stroke-width="2"
            />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox

Comment: > The coordinates returned are with respect to the current SVG space
Then do you need to do the svg space to global document space conversion yourself?

Comment: The problem in your snippet is that the transform **also** applies on the `#overlay` element, if it didn't,the values returned by gBCR would match perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/huntda7f/ Can you move your overlay out of this transformed container?

Comment: @Weilory getBBox() does not take account for transforms. Once a transformation is applied, it is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot set your overlay element outside of the transformed element, this answer will work, but only for some simple transformations:

- translations and
- scales with factors > 0

In these cases, the corners of the bounding box aren't moved out of their top/left and bottom/right orientation. Rotations or skews, and most of the 3D transforms won'T work out.

You can then compute the resulting box values for your overlay by transforming the corners of `position` with the inverse matrix to that set for the `#app` element. The [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) and [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) interfaces help with that.

It is important to remember that `transform` sets an implicit `position: relative`, so the `top` and `left` values of the overlay are not in relation to the viewport.

```js
const app = document.querySelector('#app');
const relative = app.getBoundingClientRect();

const target = document.querySelector("#overlayTarget");
const position = target.getBoundingClientRect();

const matrix = new DOMMatrix(app.style.transform).inverse();

const topleft = new DOMPoint(
     position.x - relative.x,
     position.y - relative.y
).matrixTransform(matrix);
const bottomright = new DOMPoint(
    position.x - relative.x + position.width,
    position.y - relative.y + position.height
).matrixTransform(matrix);

const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");
overlay.style.top = `${topleft.y}px`;
overlay.style.left = `${topleft.x}px`;
overlay.style.width = `${bottomright.x - topleft.x}px`;
overlay.style.height = `${bottomright.y - topleft.y}px`;
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background: hotpink;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" style="transform: scale(0.875);">
  Test
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1809" height="826" viewBox="0 0 809 826">
        <g
          id="Main_overview"
          data-name="Main overview"
          transform="translate(-49.5 -155)"
        >
          <g
            id="overlayTarget"
            data-name="DC-DC converter"
            transform="translate(400 512)"
          >
            <rect
              id="Rectangle_29"
              data-name="Rectangle 29"
              width="74"
              height="74"
              fill="none"
              stroke="#47516c"
              stroke-width="2"
            />
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
</div>
```